# Second map value is always null, even if it prints out 1

Tags: groovy, dictionary

I have some code getting data and then selecting it in order. For this I use simple maps that I may later access with ease (I thought..).

I use the following code within a loop to insert maps to another map named "companies":

```
def x = [:]
x.put(it.category[i], it.amount[i])
companies.put(it.company, x)
```

And I can surely write the result out: `[Microsoft:[Food:1], Apple:[Food:1]]`

But then, when I am about to get the food value of each company it always is `null`. This is the code I use to get the values:

```
def val = companies.get(it.company).get(key.toString())
def val = companies[it.company][key] // doesn't make a difference
```

Val is always null. Can someone help and / or explain why I have this error. What am I doing wrong? I mean, I can clearly see the `1` when I print it out..

Comment: what is `it`? what is `it.company`? what is `key`? one of them isn't what you think it is

Comment: Everything is correct, I printed them all out and it all fits. But I found the problem now. When putting the category it is not a string for some reason so a simple .toString() fixed it.

Comment: So everything wasn't correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct ;) My bad.

Comment: The problem is using a GString as a map key.  GString is written purposefully so that the checksum of equivalent-looking String and GString values are NOT equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `it.category[i]` and `key` are completely different types...

One thing you could try is:

```
x.put(it.category[i].toString(), it.amount[i])
```

and then

```
def val = companies[it.company][key.toString()] // doesn't make a difference
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple to make the category as a string:

`x.put(it.category[i].toString(), it.amount[i])`

And after that little fix it all works as expected.